# How to solve. wired gets connected only if I turn on my wifi?

Tags: 20.04, wireless, internet, wired

If I disconnect wifi/wireless connection, internet is gone even I have wired/lan connection.

Internet just fine yesterday, but now I'm facing this problem.

I tried to check this one in my windows, everything works fine. there is internet either if i connect or disconnect my wifi.

somebody knows how to fix?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Both 12.04 and 14.04 (which you have tagged) are not supported anymore.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i'm using `20.04.3 LTS`

Comment: I'd suggest applying upgrades; a fully upgraded 20.04 system should report itself as 20.04.4 which you can confirm via visiting https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ but that is the ISO release date; installed systems upgraded about a week before that date.

Comment: Can you try opening the grub menu, and booting with an older kernel?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i tried it but still same sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohh crap i just fixed it. By *"Remove Connection Profile"*, unplug the ethernet lan. And plug it again, and finally internet is back. (it automatically creates connection profile).

[image]